# ARP traffic for devices in same LAN but different subnets

Tags: subnet, arp, lan

Given a LAN with 5 devices (a,b,c,d,e). Where devices a and b are in one subnet and d,e,f are in another. Will an ARP request broadcasted by a looking for device b reach devices d, e ,f as they are all in the same broadcast (layer 2) domain?

Edit:

Layer 2 segment 1 has a, b, c, d, e

Layer 3 subnet 1 has a, b     Layer 3 subnet 2 has d, e ,f

a knows b is in the same subnet, so it broadcasts an arp request over layer 2 Ethernet. But, since d, e, and f are alos connected via Ethernet, they should also see the ARP request.

Correct or wrong (and why?)?

Comment: No. ARP is broadcast which does cross router. Routers are what routes packets between networks. If the destination host is on a different network than the source host, the source host will use a frame for its configured gateway, rather than for the destination host.

Comment: @RonMaupin Doesnt ARP use layer 2 switches though?

Comment: Switches are transparent devices, and they know nothing about things like ARP. ARP relates a layer-3 IPv4 address to a layer-2 MAC address, and that is done by the source host. The source host can tell if the destination host is on a different network, and it will use ARP to get the gateway MAC address if the destination host is on a different network.

Comment: @RonMaupin device b is on the same subnet. So a will broadcast an arp request to all devices using ethernet. And since devices a,b,c,d,e,f are all connected through ethernet, why wont the arp request reach devices d,e,f? Devices are all in the same LAN segment (connected in layer 2) but in different subnets (layer 3).

Comment: An ARP request will reach all the devices, but the devices not the target of the ARP request will ignore the ARP request. The point is that a source host will not send an ARP request for a destination host on a different network; it will use ARP to find its configured gateway for destination hosts on a different network.

Comment: @RonMaupin I never asked if the device from one subnet will send ARP request for one in another subnet. I just wanted to know if ARP requests can reach layer-2-connected devices even if they are not layer-3-connected. Your answer means yes.

Comment: Yes all broadcasts hit every host on a layer-2 broadcast domain, but the ARP requests are simply dropped when the host is not the target of the ARP request. What you mean by the host sees the ARP request is up for interpretation. The IPv4 process of the host does not see the ARP request.

Comment: If the machines are in the same L2 broadcast domain, they will see the ARP. They will only answer if their respective route table has a local ("interface") route to the destination network. This has been answered in all of the various ways multiple times. (I've run networks like this for 3 decades. While it has always been a poor practice -- one step away from proxy-arp, it does work.)

Comment: @RonMaupin nite however that there are instances where the router itself will proxy arp on behalf of devices across subnets

Comment: @MattDouhan, the question is different than that. Yes, there may be proxy ARP on a router (a giant security hole that should be avoided), but the question was about host on the same layer-2 domain hearing ARP requests from/to hosts on a different layer-3 network. Proxy ARP on a router would not even get involved in that.

Comment: @RonMaupin yes this is possible and sometimes very useful in cases where you cannot change IP of a host for whatever obscure reason and a machine POPs up on a different subnet with an IP that does not belong there but still works, so there are instances where L2 hosts can hear broadcasts from a diff L3 network , its not very common but it can be setup to do so in rare circomstances, VMOTION in a LISP enabled network comes to mind as one where we have done this etc

Comment: @MattDouhan, but the point is that the ARP was for a host on one network to the same network, would the hosts on the other network hear it? Yes, they would get the broadcast, but they would simply drop it and not do anything with it. That has nothing to do with the situation you are describing

Comment: @RonMaupin to many definition problems here